# script to serve from url, for requests matching regular expression

Tags: python, mitmproxy

I am a complete n00b in Python and am trying to figure out a stub for mitmproxy.
I have tried the documentation but they assume we know Python so i am at a stalemate.

I've been working with a script:

```
original_url = 'http://production.domain.com/1/2/3'
new_content_path = '/home/andrepadez/proj/main.js'
body = open(new_content_path, 'r').read()

def response(context, flow):
    url = flow.request.get_url()
    if url == original_url:
        flow.response.content = body
```

As you can predict, the proxy takes every request to 'http://production.domain.com/1/2/3' and serves the content of my file.

I need this to  be more dynamic:
for every request to 'http://production.domain.com/*', i need to serve a correspondent URL, for example:
http://production.domain.com/1/4/3 -> http://develop.domain.com/1/4/3

I know i have to use a regular expression, so i can capture and map it correctly, but i don't know how to serve the contents of the develop url as "flow.response.content".

Any help will be welcome

Answer (score 1):

You would have to do something like this:

```
import re

# In order not to re-read the original file every time, we maintain
# a cache of already-read bodies.
bodies = { }

def response(context, flow):
    # Intercept all URLs
    url = flow.request.get_url()
    # Check if this URL is one of "ours" (check out Python regexps)
    m = re.search('REGEXP_FOR_ORIGINAL_URL/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)', url)
    if None != m:
        # It is, and m will contain this information
        # The three numbers are in m.group(1), (2), (3)
        key = "%d.%d.%d" % ( m.group(1), m.group(2), m.group(3) )
        try:
            body = bodies[key]
        except KeyError:
            # We do not yet have this body
            body = // whatever is necessary to retrieve this body
                 = open("%s.txt" % ( key ), 'r').read()
            bodies[key] = body
        flow.response.content = body
```

Comment: I actually want to read the file every time, because this is for development purposes, but i think i can figure it out from this. Thanks